# Aligning configuration between separate ghc, cabal and previous installation

Tags: haskell, package, ghc, cabal

I have installed ghc (in c:\ghc) and cabal (in c:\cabal) separately from [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_8_1.html#windows64) and [here](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html), respectively.

I also have a folder from a previous (now uninstalled) installation named C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\cabal 700mb in size which has following folders and files:

```
13-09-2019  08:40    <DIR>          .
13-09-2019  08:40    <DIR>          ..
13-09-2019  07:00             5,519 config
12-09-2019  12:40             5,519 config.backup
13-09-2019  08:40    <DIR>          logs
12-09-2019  14:26    <DIR>          packages
13-09-2019  08:39    <DIR>          store
               2 File(s)         11,038 bytes
               5 Dir(s)   3,257,618,432 bytes free
```

I now want to configure both ghc and cabal to use c:\cabghc folder. How can I do this while also moving existing packages to this folder? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `cabal configure`. For GHC, read the follow excerpt the [ghc-pkg](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#package-databases) documentation:

> You can control GHC’s package database stack using the following
>   options:
>
> -package-db ⟨file⟩
>
> ```
> Add the package database ⟨file⟩ on top of the current stack.
> ```
>
> -no-global-package-db
>
> ```
> Remove the global package database from the package database stack.
> ```
>
> -no-user-package-db
>
> ```
> Prevent loading of the user’s local package database in the initial stack.
> ```
>
> -clear-package-db
>
> ```
> Reset the current package database stack. This option removes every previously specified package database (including those read from
> ```
>
> the GHC_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable) from the package database
>   stack.
>
> -global-package-db
>
> ```
> Add the global package database on top of the current stack. This option can be used after -no-global-package-db to specify the position
> ```
>
> in the stack where the global package database should be loaded.
>
> -user-package-db
>
> ```
> Add the user’s package database on top of the current stack. This option can be used after -no-user-package-db to specify the position
> ```
>
> in the stack where the user’s package database should be loaded.
>
> 6.9.5.1. The GHC_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable
>
> GHC_PACKAGE_PATH
>
> ```
> The GHC_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable may be set to a :-separated (;-separated on Windows) list of files containing package
> ```
>
> databases.
>   This list of package databases is used by GHC and ghc-pkg. The order is analogous to the PATH environment variable
>   where entries earlier in the PATH override ones that come later.